# Problems to set radiobutton

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="furtherMission" value="yes" /> yes
<input type="radio" name="furtherMission" value="no" /> no
```

and at an init- method I will set either yes or no with:

```
$("input[name=furtherMission][value=" + "'" + ${trainee.beu03} + "'" + "]").attr('checked', 'checked');
```

PS: ${} are the spring expressions.

but I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: yes is not defined
$("input[name=furtherMission][value=" + "'" + Ja + "'" + "]").attr('checked', 'c...
```

I have the same with numbers and there it works fine.
Does anyone have a hint how to solve this?

Comment: Check your quote nesting.  You're ending up treating Yes (or 'Ja' in your code) as a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, JavaScript thinks `yes` is a variable name. Try this in your jsp:

```
$("input[name=furtherMission][value=['${trainee.beu03}']").attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Remember that `trainee.beu03` will be evaluated in the server. It will result in this JavaScript in your HTML:

```
$("input[name=furtherMission][value=['yes']").attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to this

```
$("input[name=furtherMission][value='" + ${trainee.beu03} + "']").attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Comment: You are getting the error because `yes` is treated as a variable, not a string.Quotes might be an issue.